# Change a string macro at compilation time

Tags: c++, string, c++11, macros, compilation

I'm developing an unique client that has to work on different machines. In every machine the server is running in a different IP address, but this address is known.

I don't want to tell the client which is the IP every time I run it, so I though about tell it in compilation time.

The problem is that when compiling with `g++ -DHOSTNAME=127.0.0.1` (also tried with double quotes) the compiler is saying:

```
error: too many decimal points in number
./include/Client.h:18:25: note: in expansion of macro ‘HOSTNAME’
```

I tried it using localhost, too.

```
error: ‘localhost’ was not declared in this scope
./include/Client.h:18:25: note: in expansion of macro ‘HOSTNAME’
```

Also tried using some things found on the internet.

```
#define XSTR(x) STR(x)
#define STR(x)
```

compile error:

```
./src/BSCClient.cpp:15:45: note: #pragma message: HOSTNAME: 
#pragma message("HOSTNAME: " XSTR(HOSTNAME))

./src/BSCClient.cpp:16:39: error: too few arguments to function ‘hostent* gethostbyname(const char*)’
  server = gethostbyname(XSTR(HOSTNAME));
```

At this point I'm thinking that maybe macros isn't the proper way to handle this, but I don't figure out how to do it.

If someone has any reference about it I will be thankful.

EDIT: 
These are the codes.

Client.h:

```
#ifndef __CLIENT_HH__
#define __CLIENT_HH__

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define HOSTNAME 127.0.0.1
#define MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH 10 

class Client {
private:
    string client_name;
    int sockfd, portno;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;
    error(const char *msg);

public:

    BSCClient (string name, int port);
    void identifyme();
    void sendData (string data);
    string recvData ();

    void closeSocket();
};

#endif
```

Client.cpp

```
#include "BSCClient.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void BSCClient::error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

Client::Client(string name, int port)
{
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    portno = port;
    client_name = name;

    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");

    server = gethostbyname(HOSTNAME);

    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");

    sendData(client_name);
}

void Client::identifyme() {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = popen("id -gn", "r");

    char text[6];
    fscanf(fp, "%s", text);
    pclose(fp);
    string data(text);
    sendData(data);
}

void Client::sendData (string data) {
    const char *sdata = data.c_str();
    int n;
    n = write(sockfd, sdata, strlen(sdata));
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR writing to socket");
}

string Client::recvData () {
        int n;
        int bytes;
        char *longitud = new char[MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH+1];
        n = read(sockfd, longitud, MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH);
        if (n < 0) {
                error("ERROR recieving size of output");
        }
        bytes=atoi(longitud);
        //Para forzar el fin del string (ya que al imprimir el string hay veces que muestra caracteres de más)
        longitud[MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH]='\0';
        char *data = new char[bytes];
        n = read(sockfd, data, bytes);
        if (n < 0)
                error("ERROR reading output");
        string ret(data);
        return ret;
} 

void Client::closeSocket() {
    close(sockfd);
}
```

Comment: what is the actual code on Client.h:18?

Comment: @Niall No, it says the same. Sorry I forgot to write that I have already tried that.

Comment: @BorjaArias, Ok, it may also be useful to post the actual code that produces the error in addition to the content of the error you already have posted.

Comment: Except you didn't even copy-paste the `XSTR` trick properly. The second line is supposed to be `#define STR(x) #x`. Of course, you shouldn't blindly paste Internet code you don't understand into production code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to escape the double quotes:

```
g++ -DHOSTNAME=\"127.0.0.1\"
```

Otherwise, the quotes are just saying to your **shell** that `127.0.0.1` is the value you want to give to `-DHOSTNAME`, which can be useful if the value has whitespaces for example:

```
g++ -DMAGIC_NUMBER="150 / 5"
```

(there, `MAGIC_NUMBER` will be replaced by `150 / 5` without the quotes)

If you want the quotes to be part of the macro (as in `#define HOSTNAME "127.0.0.1"`), you have to say to your shell that they are part of the value you give to `-DHOSTNAME`, this is done by escaping them.

**EDIT**:

Also, as pointed out by Angew, you misused the XSTR trick. It is an other solution to your problem than my answer.

It certainly works like this:

```
#define XSTR(x) STR(x)
#define STR(x) #x
```

With that you don't have to escape the quotes.

These two macros change the text `127.0.0.1` into `"127.0.0.1"`. The `XSTR` macro allows `HOSTNAME` to be expanded to `127.0.0.1` before the `STR` macro converts it to `"127.0.0.1"`. If you used directly the `STR` macro, you would end up with `"HOSTNAME"` instead of `"127.0.0.1"`.

I think I prefer the escaping solution to the use of a trick involving two macros in the code, but that works too.

Comment: Thank you, that works. Today I forget to add the #x. But the past week I'm sure that I wrote it. Anyway, now it's working.

Comment: Escaping the double quotes doesn't work. The compiler print the same error as without escaping it.

Comment: Did you escape them exactly as in my first example? Also, did you remove the `#define HOSTNAME 127.0.0.1` in your code? (if you didn't, you should see a warning about HOSTNAME being redefined)

Answer (score 0):

It seems odd that you'd want to hard-code this into the executable.  It should be more flexible to use something like `getenv("MY_SERVER_ADDR")` and just set that environment variable before running your server.  Or of course you could do the more typical thing and take it as a command line argument, but something tells me you already decided not to do that.

A slightly weirder idea if you are on Linux is to write the IP address into a text file and create an ELF object file from that using `ld` and `objcopy`; you can then load this into your app as a shared object or even a static one if you really want to "hard code" it.  But I'm not sure why this would be preferable to the previously mentioned options.

Comment: I'm working in a multiuser system, so for security reasons I prefer to avoid using a environmental variable.

Comment: What about a configuration file (it can be a single-line file with the hostname inside) that users could not write to?